# How to insert a tuple into row of pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to insert a row of values into a DataFrame based on the values in a tuple. Below is an example where I want to insert the values from names['blue'] intp columns 'a' and 'b' of the DataFrame.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['red', 'blue', 'green'], 'a': [1,np.nan,2], 'b':[2,np.nan,3]})
names = {'blue': (1,2),
         'yellow': (5, 5)}
```

Note I have an attempt below (note 'a' and 'b' will always have missing together):

```
names_needed = df.loc[df['a'].isnull(), 'name']
subset_dict = {colour:names[colour] for colour in names_needed}
for colour, values in subset_dict.items():
    df.loc[df['name']==colour, ['a','b']]=values
```

I think there has to be a more elegant solution, possibly using some map function?

Answer (score 0):

Applying a `lambda` function over the rows where there are missing values, and then unpacking the values appropriately:

```
names_needed = df.loc[df['a'].isnull(), 'name']
subset_dict = {colour:names[colour] for colour in names_needed}    

mask = df['name'].isin(list(subset_dict.keys()))
df.loc[mask, ['a', 'b']] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: subset_dict.get(x["name"]), axis=1).values[0]
```

Then gives you:

```
df
    name    a   b
0   red     1.0 2.0
1   blue    1.0 2.0
2   green   2.0 3.0
```